# Return datatype function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL notices me the error that looks like this:

> ERROR: The result data return destination is not specified in the query

Here is my original creating function code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.scrolltable(
    IN p_pagenumber integer,
    IN p_pagesize integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, id character varying, rn bigint) AS
$BODY$
    Declare v_startRow int;
 v_endRow int;Begin


    v_startRow := (p_pagenumber - 1) * p_pagesize + 1;
    v_endRow := p_pagenumber * p_pagesize;

    With Result as (
        Select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By "ID" ASC)
        From "Training"
    )

    select * from Result
    Where row_number Between v_startRow AND v_endRow;

End;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I have tried to run only select queries, and it shown the table like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|<Name>                   |  <ID>                      |  <row_number> |
|<character varying(100)> |  <character varying(100)>  |  <bigint>     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have returned the right datatypes for result table, but why i still get this error?

UPDATED:
Thanks for all your answers. I have fixed the error successfully with this kind:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.scrolltable(
    IN p_pagenumber integer,
    IN p_pagesize integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, id character varying, rownumber bigint) AS
$BODY$
    Declare v_startRow int;
 v_endRow int;Begin


    v_startRow := (p_pagenumber - 1) * p_pagesize + 1;
    v_endRow := p_pagenumber * p_pagesize;

    RETURN QUERY With Result as (
        Select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By "ID" ASC)
        From "Training"
    )

    select * from Result
    Where row_number Between v_startRow AND v_endRow;

End;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Because it's plpgsql, you don't return values via `SELECT`, and you can't just do a `SELECT` without putting that data somewhere - hence the error. I think doing something like `RETURN (WITH ... AS (...) SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... );` will work.

Comment: You've missed the `return query` clause...

Comment: Thank you very much, #eurotrash, you have saved my life.